# How to get the difference of two variables, when there are missing values?

Tags: stata

I have two variables `A` & `B`, and I want to get `A - B` for a new variable called `C`. For that I used `generate C = A - B`. But it gives some missing values in `C`, when either `A` or `B` contains missing values.

For example, if `A` is 5000 while `B` is missing, it gives missing for `C`, even though I want `C` as 5000.

So I want to consider those missing values as zeros & get the answer. How can I do it in Stata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 gen C = cond(missing(A, B), min(A, B), A - B)
```

which is short-hand for

```
 gen C = A - B 
 replace C = min(A, B) if missing(A, B)
```

which is short for

```
 gen C = A - B 
 replace C = B if missing(A) 
 replace C = A if missing(B)
```

For a tutorial on `cond()` see http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0016

The result of `min(A, B)` is always the single non-missing value when there is one. (Also, true of `max(A, B)` in fact.)

You didn't spell out what you want if both are missing; the code here returns missing as the difference.

If your missings really are to be thought of as zeros, see `help mvencode`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. But it generates positive values when A is missing, even though I want it as negative. Therefore I used following code.

destring A, replace 

destring B, replace

replace A = 0 if A==.

replace B = 0 if B==.

gen C=A-B

if there is any easy & efficient method except my code, I would like to learn it.

Comment: Basic mathematics implies that positive minus zero yields positive (and also that zero minus negative yields positive). So what you get is a logical consequence of what you asked for. If for some unexplained reason you want something else, the remedy lies in your own hands: negate the answer with a minus sign. Also, it's new to this comment that your variables come as `string`: if so you will indeed need to `destring` them or equivalently to apply `real()`. I gave you short and longer solutions and documentation sources, so I don't understand what and why you don't understand.

Comment: yeah I'm really sorry it's my fault that I didn't mention about string variables. Honestly I didn't want to negate your answer. It really helped me. Thanks a million.

Comment: I meant: turn a positive number into a negative number with a minus sign. Reference was to arithmetic, not voting.

Comment: Sir, since I'm still new to stata, even a little thing is very useful to me. I could learn about cond() & mvencode because of your answer. So, I thought it will be worthy to other people as well who are having the same problem as mine. That's why I voted & as a gratitude for your great help as well. Thank you.