# How to replace a zero-valued answer by its respective average value?

Tags: stata

I have a household data set which includes expenditures for various foods. I categorized them into main food groups and price is obtained by dividing the expenditure value by quantity. For some households price comes as zero since their consumption with respect to the corresponding food group is zero. In such cases, I want to get the price as the average price of the corresponding city, district & province, which that non-consumed household is selected.

How could I do it using STATA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean of the positive values is

```
egen mean_price = mean(price / (price > 0)), by(province district city)
```

and you can replace zeros in a clone by

```
gen price2 = cond(price > 0, price, mean_price)
```

The division trick can be explained like this. If `price > 0` is true, then that expression evaluates to 1; and if false to 0. Dividing by 1 clearly leaves values unchanged. Dividing by 0 creates missings, which `egen`'s `mean()` function will ignore, which is precisely what is wanted.

There is more discussion of related technique in the article referred to in http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055

P.S. Stata is the correct spelling. It is an invented word, and was never an acronym.

P.S. You have yet to acknowledge an answer at [How to get the difference of two variables, when there are missing values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795283/how-to-get-the-difference-of-two-variables-when-there-are-missing-values)

LATER:

In this case another way is

```
  egen total = total(price), by(province district city)
  egen number = total(price > 0), by(province district city) 
  gen price2 = cond(price > 0, price, total/number)
```

as zero prices make no difference to the total. Use `double`s throughout.